# Criar variáveis personalizadas

Tags: php, css

Bem, estou com uma pulga aqui, atrás da orelha e não estou conseguindo resolver o seguinte problema:

```
  $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE client_email='$xemail'");
  $row = $select->num_rows;
  $linhas = 0;
  while($linhas < $row) {
  $get = $select->fetch_array();
  $top_1 = $get[0];
  $top_2 = $get[1];
  $top_3 = $get[2];
  $top_4 = $get[3];
  $top_5 = $get[4];
  $top_6 = $get[5];
  $top_7 = $get[6];
  $top_8 = $get[7];
  $top_9 = $get[8];
  $top_10 = $get[9];
  $top_11= $get[10];
  $top_12 = $get[11];
  $linhas++;
  }
  echo '<div id="transaction_id">'.$top_2.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="client_email">'.$top_3.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="payment_method">'.$top_4.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="payment_method_transaction">'.$top_5.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="transaction_status">'.$top_6.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="transaction_date">'.$top_7.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="transaction_date_last">'.$top_8.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="product">'.$top_9.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="product_value">'.$top_10.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="client_name">'.$top_11.'</div>';
  echo '<div id="status">'.$top_12.'</div>';
```

Basicamente isso vai pegar todos as compras feitas para o e-mail daquele cliente. Mas o problema é que as variáveis não poderiam se chamar $top_1, elas deveriam receber um numero adicional a cada vez que o loop se repetisse, depois do top_12 e fosse voltar para o top_1, ao invés de top_1 fosse top_13 e assim por diante... e dar um echo na variável pra poder pegar ela no CSS... nem sei se esse titulo seria o ideal, mas procurei a respeito no Google e não achei nada, sinceramente não sabia nem como pesquisar esse problema... :(

O que eu quero fazer é pegar todos os dados das compras e exibir eles em uma página para o cliente. O sistema vai ler uns 5 registros e depois vai exibir a página 2, e assim por diante... Nem sei se esse script é a melhor forma de fazer isso rs... mas foi a que eu testei e deu +- certo. É possível criar essas variáveis com nomes diferentes conforme o loop se repetir? Existe uma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que isso resolva seu problema:

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE client_email='$xemail'");

    while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
      $top[$count] = $row['nomeDaColuna'];
      $count++;
    }

    echo '<div id="transaction_id">'.$top[0].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="client_email">'.$top[1].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="payment_method">'.$top[2].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="payment_method_transaction">'.$top[3].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="transaction_status">'.$top[4].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="transaction_date">'.$top[5].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="transaction_date_last">'.$top[6].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="product">'.$top[7].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="product_value">'.$top[8].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="client_name">'.$top[9].'</div>';
    echo '<div id="status">'.$top[10].'</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

O certo nesse caso seria usar um array multidimensional.
E também não é uma boa usar o mysqlli [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Acho uma solução bacana assim:

Primeiramente substituir o mysqlli por PDO:

```
<?php
$ret = array();
$contador = 0;
try{
$db = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE client_email='?'");
$query->excute(array($xemail));
while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
   $ret[$contador]['transaction_id'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['client_email'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['payment_method'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['payment_method_transaction'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['transaction_status'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['transaction_date'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['transaction_date_last'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['product'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['product_value'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['client_name'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $ret[$contador]['status'] = $row->nomeDaColuna;
   $contador++;
}
}catch(PDOException  $e ){
echo "Error: ".$e;
}
?>
```

Pronto agora seu objeto foi populado de forma segura. Para renderizar seria algo assim:

```
<?php
   foreach($ret as $value){
      foreach($value as $key=>$v){
         echo "<div id='$key'>$v</div>";
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Brother, creio que confundiu, funções mysqli_ com mysql_ . Até onde sei ainda não existem, contrapostos em relação as funções mysqli_.

Comment: E, eu ia dizer o mesmo, acho que ele se confundiu... mysql e mysqli são diferentes, o mysql foi depreciado e não recebe mais atualizações, o mysqli continua normal... tanto que na referência dele explica exatamente isso, que o mysql foi depreciado, e agora o uso correto seria o mysqli

Comment: Mas gostei desse foreach, não entendo muito sobre programação... então logo vou dar uma olhada sobre ele. Enquanto vou esperar pra ver se surgem mais respostas.

Comment: Você pode usar o aproach que achar melhor com o mysql. MInha solução é essa =]